# having difficulty in setting the text field to exact size

Tags: html, css

i want to set my text field using `position:absolute` so that it occupies the whole width of parent div. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitladhania/Dqarx/1/)  for my question. I tried to do it with absolute, but in my browser covers the whole body and disappears. i can also use `width = 100%` . Which you can see I have used, but still the text field moves out of the 
parent div. thanks in advance.

```
div.middle_form_container
{
width:auto;
padding:0px;
margin:15px 10px;
border:solid 1px red;
}
div.middle_form_container > form
{
width:auto;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div.sign_up_form_text
{
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
margin:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding:0px;
}
div.name
{
width:48%;
margin:0px;
margin-right:0px;
float:left;
padding:0px;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
div.first_name
{
margin-right:12px;
}
.sign_up_form
{
position:relative;
}
.sign_up_form > input[type=text],.sign_up_form > input[type=email],.sign_up_form >     input[type=password]
{
margin:0px 0 20px 0;
padding:10px;
border:solid 1px #555;
border-radius:6px;
font-family:"Merriweather Sans";
font-size:19px;
outline:none;
}
input.name
{
width:100%;
}
div.other_text_form
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
input.other_text
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: You have `padding` on your inputs, and due to the box-model this increases the width of the elements. You could change the padding to `%` and then reduce the input width to `98%`. Or have a look at the `CSS3 box-sizing property.

Answer (score 1):

Padding, by default, sits *outside* the width of an element.

So, assuming a div has the following CSS: `width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid black;`, the border drawn will surround a 140x140px square.

This also applies using percentages. So `width: 100%; padding: 20px;` would create a box 100% **PLUS** 40px (2x20px) wide.

Therefore, you can avoid this in one of 2 ways:

1. Account for the padding in the width (e.g. use `width: 98%; padding: 1%` = 100% width)
2. Use the `box-sizing: border-box;` property (width: 100%; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box;` = 100% width)

The second option makes the padding **INSIDE** the width as illustrated:
[image: Illustration showing the effects of box-sizing]

[Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) both explain this better than I can.

You'll want to include vendor prefixes too:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: what if i want to use absolute positioning

Comment: this should make no difference

Comment: simply adding `position: absolute;` will suffice. You could also not set the width to 100% and just set `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: i did this but the text field vanishes in jsfiddle and in browser itoccupies the whole page

Comment: make the parent element have `position: relative`. `position: absolute` makes the element absolute in terms of the closest parent with `position: relative`. This is the default for `body`.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.name ,input.other_text{width:96%;
                             padding:10px 2%;}
```

Comment: i want the text field to occupy the whole parent div

Comment: you are using padding in input 10px and width 100%, that is why the input fields are overflowing form their parent divs, you need to reduce left and right padding or width of the text fields.